# Where can I configure SELinux in Cyanogenmod 10.1.3?

Tags: cyanogenmod, security, kernel, selinux

Cyanogenmod released the stable version [10.1.3](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/28/cyanogenmod-10-1-3-android-4-2-2-release-candidate-1-is-ready-to-download/) yesterday and it apparently includes SELinux enhancements [running in permissive mode](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cyanogenmod-10-1-3-rc1) per default.

I thought that you could change the mode in the settings, but so far I have not found anything.

Is this possible at all using the graphical touch interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Settings -> About phone` menu and scroll all the way to the bottom:
[image]

Tap the "SELinux status" menu 3 times in a row in a quick succession.  This will bring up a prompt asking you to confirm enabling the other modes:
[image]

Be aware that currently this feature is still under heavy development, and isn't supported on all devices yet.

Comment: I don't even see a "SELinux status" entry. Not sure if my device is supported, but since I have a Galaxy Nexus S I'd think yes.

Comment: It should be under `Settings -> About phone` menu, all the way at the bottom.

Comment: Well, I don't have this option. But you run 10.2! I'm running 10.1.3-crespo which is based on Android 4.2.2. While Android 4.2.2 does not feature SELinux, Cyanogenmod decided to include it already in their firmware for 10.1.3 when they originally introduced [10.1.3-RC1](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/blog/cyanogenmod-10-1-3-rc1). Maybe an update on the blog in the next few day will explain what going on.