# What is persist.security.ams.enforcing?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp

I have a galaxy s6 and was looking to install custom roms. Unfortunately, when I successfully install a custom Rom, it doesn't boot up. So I looked online and one website said something about Seandroid enforcing issues. So when I went to default prop.l, I found that line of code. The value is set to 1. What happens if I disable it and is it interfering with the kernel or Rom flashing? I also got rid of all the Knox apps too.

So what exactly is persist.security.ams.enforcing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
persist.security.ams.enforcing
```

It's the bane of existence. While this is Set to 1, your SELinux state is **enforcing**([Click here for a snippet of info](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/154092/116168))

Changing that to 0 switches SELinux to **permissive**.

In layman terms, this means that, when set to Enforcing, Android is looking at your attempts to install a ROM, and is denying them. Set it to permissive, and it can't do anything(well, not much).

*SELinux does more than this too. Its a good read, that question I linked has some good info, as well as the link in **that** one.*

Comment: So is that why I haven't been able to get my custom roms loading? Also, I just disabled it by switching the value to 0 but it keeps switching to 1 when I boot up! How do you permanently disable it? Also, is there anything else in the build.prop that I should disable before flashing a custom rom?

Comment: @RyanNoles use 'setenforce' (no quote marks) in a terminal to view what to do to change your SELinux status. Also, Most Custom ROMS tweak the build.prop themselves, so I doubt other tweaks are needed. I never had to tweak mine for Custom ROMS.

Comment: I think I figured it out! According to one post, one guy said he was having trouble installing the Xposed and getting it to boot up because Android SElinux is set to enforce by default! Maybe if I permanently disable SEandroid enforcing, I might be able to get Xposed to work! I will try your option (the sentenforce technique) and see what happens! I was really wanting Xposed but couldn't get it because of my crappy odexed touchwiz rom

Comment: @RyanNoles alright. Good luck!

Comment: It did not work! No matter how hard I try, I can't disable SElinux in my kernel!!! I even tried it with a terminal but no luck! Do you think there is a hidden knox setting in my phone? I thought I removed all the knox apps, but I am still seeing info of the knox versions in the settings/about phone!

Comment: No idea, to be fair. The kernel *might* be switching it back on, but I don't have a S6 To experiment. All I can say is: Google?